# React: Dynamically adding and removing Key-Value pair from state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I'm right now working on a dynamic form but still need to implement the removing of the item in the state object when the input gets removed visually.
[image]
The creation and removing of the Form.Item and input gets managed by Ant Design but the implementation with the state is the part I'm struggling with. This is the extract of the JSX where the inputs get created and removed. The functions `add()` and `remove()` come from Ant design and create and remove a form item visually:

```
{current === 1 &&
  <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" autoComplete="off" onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Form.List name="allergy">
      {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
        <>
          {fields.map(field => (
            <Form.Item
              {...field}
              name={[field.fieldKey]}
              fieldKey={[field.fieldKey]}
              rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Missing allergy' }]}
              style={{ marginBottom:8 }}
            >
              <Input
                placeholder="Your allergy"
                style={{ marginRight:4 }}
                name={field.fieldKey}
                onChange={e => onChangeInput(e)}
              />
              <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => {remove(field.name); const allergy=field.fieldKey ; const newFormData = Object.values(formData).filter((formData)=>(allergy !== allergy)); setFormData( newFormData)}}/>
            </Form.Item>
          ))}
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="dashed" onClick={() => add()} block icon={<PlusOutlined />}>
              Add allergy
            </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </>
      )}
    </Form.List>
  </Form>
}
```

This is my implementation of adding the input to the state object but I'm struggling to remove the object when also removing the input visually.
I have right now added my idea after the `remove()` function in the JSX. But filtering the state doesn`t work because it always removes every item in the state.

```
const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

const onChangeInput = e => {
  setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
};
```

My idea is to check the state and create a new object that includes every object except the one with the `field.fieldKey` (example: 0 or 1 ...) of the currently clicked(removed) field.
I hope my problem is understandable and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue by first creating a new object with the current state and than deleting the key-value pair of the deleted field in the newly created object (newFormData). After that I set the newFormData as the current state.
The `delete``function only returns true/false so we have to create a new object and use that as the new state object to keep the data immutable.

```
<MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => {remove(field.name); const newFormData = formData; delete newFormData[field.fieldKey]; setFormData(newFormData)}}/>
```